# Api App Sqlconnector not allowing Hybrid setup

Tags: azure, azure-hybrid-connections

Trying to configure my SQL Connector API App named (CENTRAL.SQLCONNECTOR.EMPLOYEESYNC.DEV) to use the Hybrid Connection Manager.  I have had to delete it and recreate multiple times assessing the query options, and confused because it seems very inconsistent to allow the Hybrid Connection setup.  It currently reads below...

Hybrid Connection
Not configured as a hybrid ApiApp

The prior time it allowed it fine, and I was able to successfully setup the Hybrid Connection Manager on my web server.  Could you please look at this api app, and maybe tell me what I may be doing wrong.

Thanks